# How to extract exactly the same word with regexp_extract_all in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, extract

I have some issues in finding the correct regular expression.

Lets say I have this list of keywords:

keywords = [' b.o.o', ' a.b.a', ' titi']

(please note that there is a blank space before any keyword and this list can contain up to 100keywords so I can't to it without a function)

and my dataframe df:

[image]

I use the following code to extract the matching words, it works partially because it extract even the words that are not an exact match :

```py
keywords = [' b.o.o', ' a.b.a', ' titi']

pattern = '(' + '|'.join([fr'\\b({k})\\b' for k in keywords]) + ')'

df.withColumn('words', F.expr(f"regexp_extract_all(colB, '{pattern}' ,1)))
```

Actual output :

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

As we can see, it does extract words that are not exact match, it does not take into account the dot.  For example, this code considers awbwa as a match because if we replace w by a dot it will be a match. I also tried:

```py
pattern = '(' + '|'.join([fr'\\b({k})\\b' for k in [re.escape(x) for x in keywords]]) + ')'
```

to add a backslash before every dot and before the blank space but it doesnt work.

I searched on stackoverflow; but didnt find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure it out,  for some reason re.escape doesnt work, the solution was to add [] in between dots.